# Increment Alphabet Characters By Numeric Value

Tags: java

I need a java method that takes in an integer and then increments it and gives you the respective alpha character. Something like this:

```
public String getAlpha(Integer number) {
   ...
}
```

So if I pass the `number` value equal `0` then it should increment and return the letter `a`. If I pass it `25` then it should return the letter `z`. If I pass it the number `26` then it should return `aa`. If I pass it the number `27` then it should return `ab` and so on.

The alpha's pretty much simulate the way excel sheet columns are represented, all I need to do is get the alpha value from a method by passing it a number. There is no set limit except the String that gets returned from `getAlpha` must be a maximum of `15` chars and a minimum of `1` char.

Comment: Is it your homework? If so - please tag it as such. Also: What did you already try?

Comment: So you want to translate numbers from base-10 to base-26.

Comment: @ThreaT:Why does the `26` should return `aa`?When would you get `ba` or `aaa`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will do what you want, I don't know if it can be done more efficiently:

```
static void printCode(int code) {
  final StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
  do {
    final int digit = (code - 1) % 26;
    buffer.insert(0, (char)(digit + 'a'));
    code = (code - digit - 1) / 26;
  } while (code > 0);
  System.out.println(buffer);
}
```

Comment: I understand what @Marko Topolnik says.. it is not as excel does it.. I probably didn't understand it in the beginning quite right. However OP  is being confused as well

Comment: Some words of advice, OP: 1. dividing by 25 is wrong; 26 must be used; instead of `buffer.append('z')` you must use `buffer.append((char)(code % 26 + 'a'))`

Comment: Alright, revamped it to close to what I would write. Use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`, don't try to guess the size, it's not necessary; use do-while instead of while to avoid repeated code, order characters properly by prepending instead of appending.

Comment: BTW proper size guessing requires taking the 26th root of the number. Why do it. One could approximate by shifting right by 4 (divide by 16, slight overkill).

Comment: The whole thing should be 1-based, not 0-based, only then can it work properly. Let's fix it.

Comment: Fixed it finally. It really isn't trivial. I used a solution from elsewhere on StackOverflow, though, solutions are really easy to come by.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik specified that the code is set to work 1-based instead of 0-based. So you either set your new starting point (of 'a') to 1 or just add one to the inputs before processing.

Comment: But it must be obvious that it is a trivial intervention to make the same function 0-based as seen from outside. For example, add the line `code++;` to the beginning of the method. The 1-based nature of it stems from the fact that "z" is followed by "aa", which would be like 9 was followed by 11.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you generate a - z from numbers between 0 and 25 in Java:

```
protected static String getLetter(int code) {
    if (code >= 0 && code <= 25)
        return "" + (char) (code  + 'a');
    else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("char code is out of bound: " + code);
}
```

the rest is just modulo Math.

Comment: This is overly complex. Either just `""+(char)(code + 'a')` or `new String(new char[]{code+'a'});` and the best option would be `String.valueOf((char)(code+'a'))`

Comment: indeed, I extracted it from a method I had doing more things, but I would not say its complex, its just verbose

Comment: *Just verbose* would mean it had no runtime effects, but it does imply a redundant instance of `String`.

Comment: oh ok, I assumed wrongly `new String(String)` was not copying the immutable object, I was wrong sorry

Comment: However, it doesn't really answer the question since it has no setting for what happens after a-z, or am I not understanding something?

Comment: Yes, it is a strong guarantee by Java semantics that each `new` expression results in a newly allocated object. Strings share their internal char arrays, but that's a different thing.

Comment: @ThreaT "the rest is just modulo math" :) This answer provides the fiddly Java API calls needed to convert from an 0-based integer to an 'a'-based char and then to String and the rest is the same as conversion of a full integer into a representation in any base.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. However, that's the hardest part and it's the reason why I asked the question in the first place ;)

Answer (score 0):

it is the same the Excel column naming:

```
public class Calculator {

    private static String[] letters = new String[]{
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(calculate(731));
    }

    public static String calculate(int row) {
        return calculateRecursive(row - 1, "");
    }

    private static String calculateRecursive(int row, String res) {
        String val = letters[row % letters.length] + res;
        int i = row / letters.length;
        if(row >= letters.length) {
            return calculateRecursive(i - 1, val);
        }
        return val;

    }
}
```